# how to deselect the active span element?

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to check the active and inactive status for `span` element. I'm working on the online movie ticket reservation system. So, if user select the seats it should change into green color. Again user can deselect the seats. So, it should change into old color. I've tried something... posted on jsfiddle. It works when i click the `span` element. But, how to deselect the active span element?

[**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/MGLXx/)

**Jquery**

```
$(".active").click(function(){
    $(this).css('background-color', 'green');
})
```

**CSS** and **HTML**

```
<span class="active">seats</span>
.active
    {
        width: 100px;
        height: 25px;
        color: #000000;
        background: #CCCCCC;
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .active
    {
        cursor: pointer;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a class called selected

```
.selected{
    background-color:green;
}
```

Then use .toggleClass to toggle the background color

```
$(this).toggleClass('selected');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/MGLXx/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Create a class for toggle and apply [`toggleClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

```
.green
{
    background:green;
}

$( "span.active" ).click(function() {
   $( this ).toggleClass( "green" );
});
```

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/MGLXx/4/)

Answer (score 1):

Try
**Script**

```
 $(".active").click(function(){

         ($(this).toggleClass('green_span');
    })
```

Style

```
.active
        {
            width: 100px;
            height: 25px;
            color: #000000;
            background: #CCCCCC;
            display: inline-block;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .active
        {
            cursor: pointer;
        }
.green_span{background:green}
```